# Get default value for serializer field from a method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I struggle to find a way to do something I thought must be very basic. I have a serializer accepting either address (nested serializer) or coordinates (also a nested serializer). If the user supplies the address, I resolve it using some magic into coordinates and I want to provide those coordinates in the response. This is what I have so far:

```py
class AddressSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    zip_code = serializers.CharField()
    city = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    street = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    house_number = serializers.CharField(required=False)

class GeoPointSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    latitude = serializers.FloatField()
    longitude = serializers.FloatField()


class TheSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    address = AddressSerializer(required=False)
    coordinates = GeoPointSerializer(required=False)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        # check if the user provided either address or coordinates

    def resolve_address_to_coordinates(...):
        ...
```

and now I have no idea how to continue. I know about `SerializerMethodField` which would work fine, except it is read-only. Then I was playing with `default` and `source` attributes on the `coordinates` field, but also no success. Can anyone unstuck me?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on the actual error?  You want to check if `a` or `b` was provided, thats just `if attrs.get("a") or attrs.get("b")`, but what is this default and source that is giving you issues.  Perhaps you could show the input you are sending to the serializer (json) and how you expect it to behave.  What you are doing doesn't sound too strange, so no worries there, and your base code looks fine.

Comment: the validation works fine, there is no problem with that... what i need is to provide the `coordinates` field in the response in case the address was filled, and to get this value, i would use `resolve_address_to_coordinates` as "default", except it does not work when i just provide it as the default... clearer now?